# Server side url scanner for malware, spyware , viruses and protect my visitors

Tags: anti-virus

I have a forum/groups site that contains a  lot of external URLs, sometimes direct download links. I want to protect my visitors from possible attacks from malware sites as they are mot likely to click on these links. CUrrently I implement DBL (spamhaus) but thats not enough. I want to run a background task to check the outgoing links first. I have looked at similar questions in StackOverflow (wrongly posted there) and here but fail to find a question same as mine or a good answer.

People have suggested ClamAV , I don't believe it can detect Web hosted malware sites and its has a lot of missed detection.
I have looked at google safe browsing service (
http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/developers_guide_v2.html
very complicated to implement or maintain plus  midway I get lost :S )

I can go for commercial solution, anything to protect the visitors and my site brand. But I would like to hear the opinion of server admins and if anyone has implemented such a service.

My Server is basic CentOS LAMP stack.

thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use 3 or 4 external site checking services, in a crontab  script.
this is written in my lang (tcsh) but easily convertible to bash/sh

I run this once a day.

Possibly a difficult part might be assembling the list of the external sites you link to.

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f 
# simplistic after the fact check/test of our sites,being possible malware related.
#Mon Sep 20 18:52:15 GMT 2010,dianevm at gmail.com
# happened once when some bogus advert networks were used for 48 hours :-(
setenv TZ CST6CDT

set LINKS="links -no-references -no-numbering -dump-width 120 -dump "
set TMPF=/tmp/.malware.dmp.$$
#alias DBG 'echo -n DEBUG:; set PAUSE=$<'
alias DBG 'echo -n " "'
set NOW=`date +%T`

alias OKOUT 'set NOW=`date +%T`;printf %-8s \!*;echo " $NOW"'


set SITES2CHECK="toplevel.com external2.com varioussite3.com etc.com"

foreach i ( $SITES2CHECK )

echo ___  $i ___  


printf %-20s GOOGLE 
$LINKS "http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=$i" >! $TMPF

set GOOGLEOK=`grep 'This site is not currently listed as suspicious' $TMPF |wc -l` 
if  ( "$GOOGLEOK" == "1" )then 
    OKOUT ok
else
   tcsh ~/malwarefail $i GOOGLE $TMPF
endif

printf %-20s SiteAdvisor  
$LINKS http://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/$i >! $TMPF
set SITEADVOK=`grep 'tested this site and didn.t find any significant problems.' $TMPF|wc -l` 
set SITEADVUNKNOWN=`grep 'we haven.t tested this one yet.' $TMPF|wc -l` 
if ($SITEADVOK == "1" || "$SITEADVUNKNOWN" == "1") then
    OKOUT  ok  
else
   tcsh ~/malwarefail $i SITEADV $TMPF
endif

printf %-20s  Norton 
$LINKS "http://safeweb.norton.com/report/show?url=$i"  >! $TMPF
set NORTONOK=`grep 'Norton Safe Web found no issues with this site' $TMPF|wc -l` 
set NORTONUNKNOWN=`grep ' This site has not been tested yet' $TMPF|wc -l` 
if ($NORTONOK == "1" ||$NORTONUNKNOWN  == "1" ) then
    OKOUT  ok  
else 
    tcsh ~/malwarefail $i NORTON $TMPF
endif
printf %-20s  BRWSDEFNDR 
$LINKS "http://www.browserdefender.com/site/$i/">! $TMPF
set BRWSDEFNDROK=`grep 'Our testing of this site found no dangerous downloads' $TMPF|wc -l` 
set BRWSDEFNDRUNKNOWN=`grep 'Not yet rated' $TMPF|head -1|wc -l` 
#note head added,2  instances 
if ($BRWSDEFNDROK == "1" ||$BRWSDEFNDRUNKNOWN  == "1" ) then
    OKOUT  ok  
else 
    tcsh ~/malwarefail $i BRWSDEFNDR $TMPF
endif
end
~
## note malwarefail just emails people the output of the dump files
```

Comment: This is a good and usable starting point. Thank you so much for sharing this. I am sure it will help someone else too. With a little bit of coding here and there anyone can adapt this.